# What does rel="nofollow me" do?

Tags: html, nofollow

I notice on SO userpage all urls have rel="nofollow me" (i was thinking of putting nofollow on my site so i checked here to see what SO does). What does the 'me' part do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a combination of two independent uses of the `rel` attribute.

- `rel="nofollow"` tells search engines to ignore the link when ranking pages.
- `rel="me"` is a [microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me)

Comment: "nofollow" doesn't mean the link should be ignored, it means it **should** be followed but should not be considered an endorsement of the URL that is linked to. It is very badly named.

Answer (score 8):

[rel="me"](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me) is a link from a page about a person to another page about the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Rel="nofollow" not to follow link or not share your website repo to that page. This page could be internal as well it could be external page. 
Rel="me" To give a social Repo to that page.

**Rel="nofollow me"** Means not to follow link but pass social repo to that page. Usually Facebook is a great example. From SEO point of view, now SEs are also considering social factors and I recommend to build your link on relevant page with high rate of traffic.

Comment: What do you mean with "repo"?

Answer (score 0):

`<a rel="me nofollow" href="https://example.org">`

"me" instructs the search engines that the external website being linked(example.com) is another expression of me. 
The page where "me" appears and the destination website listed into the href field have the same owner.