# html2pdf : Prevent the crawl of the google robot

Tags: php, html-to-pdf

I use the following script :

https://www.html2pdf.fr/en/home

This script convert my php file to pdf file.

Example the url : mywebsite.com/pdf/url.php?id=8 will generate a PDF file.
Another example : https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/examples/example01.php

I don't want the google robot to index these pages.

I added the code below in my htaccess file but it doesn't prevent google from crawling the page because it's in PHP :
#Block indexing of Word and PDF files
<files ~ ".(doc|docx|pdf)$">
Header Set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow

I can't block it how do I do it?

Comment: In the links to the PDF, put a rel no follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509022/231316

Comment: Thank you, you are right. However the pages are already indexed by the Google robot. How to unindex them?

Comment: For the existing content, log into Google Search Console and [request to have the URLs removed](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6332384). Also, update your htaccess to include rules for the URL of your dynamic PDF generator. htaccess doesn't care if it is a static file or dynamic, it is just URL patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **X-Robots-Tag** HTTP Response header in the script that generates your PDF file.

Example: `header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);`

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag#xrobotstag).